# Make a form-row shorter to accommodate a button to the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm doing a web application with bootstrap v4.4.1.

I'm trying to add a `form-row` with 2 inputs and 1 button side by side. also, I want to add a button to the right, but, the `form-row` occupies the entire row and there is no space for the button.

Working demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">

              <form>
                <div class="form-row" style="background-color: #8197B1">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="input1">* One</label>
                    <input id="input1"
                           class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="input2">* Two</label>
                    <input id="input2"
                           class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-auto">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <!-- /.form -->

              <div class="text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Export</button>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.col-12 -->
          </div>
```

I have tried different combinations with `col`, `col-auto`, etc.. but no luck so far.

My goal is to have just one `row`, in the left side the `form-row` and in the right side the green button. In other words, I would like to have the green button at the right side, in the same row.

Example of what I want:

[image]

Comment: where you want to add  the button ??

Comment: @raven404 in the same row at the right side. Right now it's located one line below.

Comment: like u want to have both the input fields and button in a row??

Comment: @raven404 yes, all in the same row, the green button should be located in the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Auto margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins):

change from:

```
<div class="text-right">
```

to:

```
<div class="col-auto ml-auto">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form>
            <div class="form-row" style="background-color: #8197B1">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="input1">* One</label>
                    <input id="input1"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="input2">* Two</label>
                    <input id="input2"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Export</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- /.form -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-12 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. A curiosity, what I don't understand is why the green button must be inside of the `form-row` div? The green button is not part of my "form", it's just a button to do something else.

Comment: Because a form-row is a row by itsef